# Remove last element from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to remove last element from

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

My code is

```
StringTokenizer stheader = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",");
while (stheader.hasMoreTokens()){
    String tmp = stheader.nextToken();
    header.add(tmp);
    System.out.println("tmp"+header);
    map.put(tmp, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
System.out.println(map.size());
```

Output:

```
tmp[Sepal_Length, Sepal_Width, Petal_Length, Petal_Width, Class]
map{Petal_Width=[], Class=[], Petal_Length=[], Sepal_Length=[], Sepal_Width=[]}
```

I want to remove the key Class[] from `map` or `tmp`.

I tried using `.remove()` but nothing is reflecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two collections effectively, so if you want the `"Class"` element removed, you need to do it in **both**. If **always** removing the **last** element of `tmp` in both collections is what you care about, and assuming `header` is a `List<String>`, you should do something like this:

```
String keyToRemove = header.remove(header.size()-1);
map.remove(keyToRemove);
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no order in `HashMap`, so, you can't remove the last item. Use `LinkedHashMap` to have the order of insertion.

Answer (score 2):

@Unmesha SreeVeni : Use `LinkedHashMap` to delete last element because `HashMap` does not maintain order of insertion of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` doesn't arrange it's elements according to an index, but you can retrieve only the element according to it's `key`, so if you have to use a `HashMap` you have to add an incremental index to it's key, so when you put a new element that index incremented with one and put with the key in the `HashMap`, like this :

```
Map<Map<int,String>, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Map<int,String>, List<String>>();
int index = 0;
StringTokenizer stheader = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",");
while (stheader.hasMoreTokens()){
    String tmp = stheader.nextToken();
    header.add(tmp);
    System.out.println("tmp"+header);
    Map<int, String> temp_map = new HashMap<int, String>();
    temp_map.put(index, tmp);
    index ++;
    map.put(temp_map, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
```

and then you can check the value of index in the end and that will be the index of the last element.